# Stray '\342' in program when doing comparisons with negative numbers

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

Every time when I do a comparison with a negative number, GCC shows me this:

```
error: stray '\342' in program
   if ( -4 < ÔÇô3 ) return 1;
   ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Code:

```
int main() {
  if ( -4 < –3 ) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a proper text editor to write your code.

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious which character is causing the problem. That's an altered hyphen. Dumb [website](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) doesn't have a way to share results that I can see, but http://i.imgur.com/Q6QtHCm.png. Compare that to a [normal hyphen](http://i.imgur.com/7tdVnWd.png).

Comment: Didn't you leave out the next two stray characters reported (they form one unit in this case)? Many of these start with 342 (octal): U+200B (342 200 213, [ZERO WIDTH SPACE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)), U+2013 (342 200 223, [EN DASH](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)), U+2014 (342 200 224, [EM DASH](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)), and U+2212 (342 210 222, [MINUS SIGN](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8704&number=128)).

Comment: OK, for the code posted here, closest to the source, it is 342 200 223. 342 200 223 (octal) → 0xE2 0x80 0x93 (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+2013 ([EN DASH](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8704&number=128)). Most text editors (e.g. [Geany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany) (Linux and Windows) and [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B)) with a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) mode will be able to do search/replace for Unicode code point U+2013, using `\x{2013}`.

Comment: Note: The notation is different in Visual Studio Code (and probably others): `\u2013` (instead of `\x{2013}`)

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dash before the number three is a Unicode character that looks like a dash. Delete it, and insert a new dash and you'll be fine.

If you used copy-paste, then beware, as pasted code can contain Unicode characters and that may lead to compilation errors like this.

If you typed it manually into an editor, use a different editor or alter the settings of the editor not to convert standard hyphens into other characters. E.g., Microsoft Word does this conversion, but I hope that you did not write code in Word.

---

The explanation of the error message:

You saved the file in UTF-8 charset. The altered hyphen you used is saved as three consecutive bytes: `0xE2 0x80 0x93` (hexadecimal values)

g++ parses the file byte by byte. It encounters `0xE2` first, which it considers invalid and outputs `error: stray '\342' in program`. The `342` is the octal representation of `0xE2`. And `\342` is valid C++ code, it is the escaped version of 0xE2 character. See C++ [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) for details, `\nnn` means the character represented by the octal `nnn` number.

Comment: You'll only be fine if you're not using an editor which automatically converts `-` to `–`. I think that is not a safe assumption: if it were, the OP wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: @hvd Thanks for the comment, I've updated the answer. I suspect some copy-paste behind the scenes.